# Can I make all fields "dirty" on attempted submission?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a CSS class that applies to all dirty and invalid fields:

```
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid, select.ng-dirty.ng-invalid, textarea.ng-dirty.ng-invalid{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

On submission, however, I would like the red border (and anything else I add too the class) to appear.

Is there a way to make all fields dirty on submission? Or apply a class to the form like "ng-formsubmitted" (or something)?

Comment: Could you provide your form code? It would be much easier to propose a solution that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the form to dirty on submit then use that in your css selector instead of the individual elements.

```
<button ng-click="formName.$setDirty();doWhatever();">Save</button>
```

or on your form depending on how you've set things up:

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="formName.$setDirty()">
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Then your css selector would be

```
.ng-dirty .ng-invalid {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to your form submission handler...

```
$('input').addClass("ng-dirty");
$('select').addClass("ng-dirty");
$('textarea').addClass("ng-dirty");
```

This code basically says to add the class `ng-dirty` to all of your form fields.

Or, if you need both classes...

```
$('input').addClass("ng-dirty").addClass("ng-invalid");
$('select').addClass("ng-dirty").addClass("ng-invalid");
$('textarea').addClass("ng-dirty").addClass("ng-invalid");
```

**AND**, as pointed out in the comments below (thanks Ingo)...  the three lines can be combined in to one as follows:

```
$('input, select, textarea').addClass("ng-dirty").addClass("ng-invalid");
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the submit button you can set the form to be dirty.

### From angularjs documentation for [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

> ```
> $setDirty();
> ```
>
> Sets the form to a dirty state.
>
> This method can be called to add the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to a dirty state (ng->dirty class). This method will also propagate to parent forms.